# How to avoid duplicate entries build errors in UWP app?

Tags: uwp, resources, visual-studio-2017

I try to create an UWP app package in VS 2017.

When creating I get a mysterious error message: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       0xdef00532 - Conflicting values for resource 'Files/Assets/Square44x44Logo.png' ProjectName C:...\GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE

and

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Duplicate entries.  ProjectName C:...\error PRI175

It seems something wrong with the image resources, but they were created the built in Asset Genetor of appxmainifest's Visual Assets tab. I did not change anything, I simply added a 400x400 png image and clicked generate, and assets are generated. There is no duplication in files.

I tried to delete, regenerate, remove, add them again etc, but neither helped.

What should I do?

Comment: Try deleting all auto-generated files in Asset and create it again

Comment: I tried it of course...but did not help! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a little X mark in any of the Image in appxmainifest?

Comment: No, there is not...

Comment: Today I encountered the same problem when using the generate-function provided in the manifest. Couldn't make it work either. I use Visual Studio Team Services, so I was able to restore a working version of my project.

Answer (score 1):

After encountering this problem myself and spending a couple of hours trying to solve it, I finally came across something that seems like a solution:

Simply make sure the assets won't be generated in folder "Assets" directly, but in a subfolder, e.g. "Assets\AppIcon". Just change the value in field "Target" accordinlgy before generating the assets!

Comment: This worked for me and also solved the error mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777283/uwp-pri277-0xdef00532-conflicting-values-for-resource

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after replacing images that were generated. I commited changes, then removed files and reverted changes. It started to work.